# how to set values in mongodb array

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

> System.NullReferenceException occurred   HResult=0x80004003
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   mongotest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\kiit\source\repos\C#-code\mongotest\mongotest\Program.cs:line
>   20

Please help me to solve this error. Why I get the null reference. Apart from this tell me how to get data in MongoDB for this schema

```
{ 

        "_id" : ObjectId("5a78a7365a98c0a0d9118c1a"), 
        "name" : "Amit", 
        "contacts" : [
            "userid1", 
            "userid2"
        ], 
        "logs" : {
            "status" : "online", 
            "Available" : "False"
        }
    }
```

Code :
how to set value for logs and contacts,I want to insert these value in database. 
What I will do with this solution: I will insert value in a database on click event in asp.net and take values from the user.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    namespace mongotest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                /* Connection in MongoDb and insert data in database */
                var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
                var database = client.GetDatabase("SIH");
                var collection = database.GetCollection<testing>("testing");
                testing newobject = new testing();
                newobject.name = "Amit Mishra";
                newobject.logs.Available = "true";
                newobject.logs.status = "false";
                collection.InsertOneAsync(newobject);
                Console.Write("Done");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }

    public class testing
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string[] contacts { get; set; }
        public Logs logs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Logs
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string Available { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It is a bit of a beginner programmer mistake: the error message says exactly what the problem is: code has not been initialized on line 20. So simply check what it is you are trying to do there and notice that the 'logs' property has not been initialized.

Comment: Thanks Could you please help me to know how to "contacts" : [ "userid1", "userid2" ], set these value (userid1 and userid2)

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing a non-initialized property which is why you're getting the NullPointerException.

Change your code to this instead:

```
[...]
newobject.logs = new Logs();
newobject.logs.Available = "true";
[...]
```

Comment: Could you please help me to know how to "contacts" : [
            "userid1", 
            "userid2"
        ],  set these value (userid1 and userid2)

Comment: Kindly see the other answer given below for that.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by dnickless, you have to initialize the logs, and you have to initialize the string array as well.
In your case the code should be enhanced to something like:

```
[...]
newobject.logs = new Logs();
newobject.logs.Available = "true";
newobject.contacts = new string[]{ "userid1", "userid2" };
[...]
```